# If cosB=3/4, how do I find cos 2B and cos(B/2)?

Tags: trigonometry

I got $\cos 2B$;
$\cos 2B=2 \cos^2 B - 1
             =9/8 -1
              =1/8$

but when I tried cos1/2B, I got: COS1/2B=cos^2*1/4B-1, then I solved it, and didn't get the answer which was in the book, why?

Comment: $\cos B=2\cos^2\frac B2-1$.

Comment: But why can't we use cos1/2B if we need to find that? For cos2B we use cos2B=... not something else

Comment: You could, but you don't have a value for $\cos \frac B4$, so that doesn't help.  Also please use parentheses.  It is clearer to say cos(B/2) than cos 1/2B as the B could be in the denominaor.  Better yet, learn to use MathJax as shown in the FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Since $\cos 2b =\cos^2 b-\sin^2 b =2\cos^2 b -1$, we have
$$\cos b= \cos 2(\tfrac12 b)=2\cos^2 \tfrac12b-1$$
$$\cos\tfrac12 b =\pm\sqrt{\tfrac12(1+\cos b)}$$

Comment: Yeah, I tried that one now, and that works, but why do we use the equation for cos B, if it asks for cos 1/2B?

Comment: @JohnFire : Because you're looking for an equation that lets you write $\cos \frac12 b$ in terms of $\cos b$. So if you have an equation containing both, you can solve it for one expression in terms of the other.

Answer (score 2):

Hint

$$\cos x= 2\cos^2(x/2)-1$$

Comment: Yeah, but if we use the formula for cos2x when we find cos2B, then why don't we use the formula for cos1/2x if we find cos1/2B, and why do we use cosx's formula?

Comment: But if you need $B/2$ why are you looking for $1/(2B)$?

Comment: Because B/2 = 1/2 B? Same thing

Comment: I think someone is confusing $1/(2b)$ and $(1/2)b$. Without parentheses, the in-line fraction notation is ambiguous.

Comment: Oh, I see: you mean $B/2=(1/2)B$. You can do that but see that you are going down with the angle. If you start with $B$ and want $B/2$ is not a good idea use the formula for $B/2$, because like you saw, you go down with the angle.

Comment: @Arnaldo Yeah, sorry i need to get used to the formatting. What do you mean by going down with the angle?

Comment: @JonhFire: I mean, if you use $B/2$ At the left side of the formula you get $B/4$ at the right site (the angle goes down). But you have $B$, That is why is better start with $B$ at the left side and get $B/2$. Is it clear?

Comment: @Arnaldo Oh, okay, I get it now, thank you :)

Comment: @JohnFire: you are very welcome

Answer (score 1):

$\cos 2B = 2 \cos^2 B - 1 
= \frac9{8} - 1 = \frac{1}{8}$

Second answer -

$\cos B = 2 \cos^2(\frac B2) - 1$

$\frac34 = 2 \cos^2(\frac B2) - 1$

$\frac 74 =  2 \cos^2(\frac B2)$

$\frac 78 =  \cos^2(\frac B2)$

$\sqrt{\frac78} =  \cos (\frac B2)$

$\frac12 \sqrt{\frac72} = \cos (\frac B2)$